# Bookmark position Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, bookmarks

I'm trying to put a folder in the sidebar in a specific position in `nautilus` like `Images` folder et al, with no success, I tried setting bookmarks and change the `user-dirs.dirs`.

Here some screenshots for a better reference:

Position:
[image: position]

What actually happens:
[image: what actually happens]

`user-dirs.dirs` config:
[image: user dirs config]